# How lazy loading works for collection of objects?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, set, hibernate-mapping

I have One-to-Many association and **FetchType** is LAZY. 
 
I know that hibernate will create the proxy object for lazy loaded entity. But how does it works if child entity is Collection type ? Will it create proxy for each collection object ?
Example:-

```
 public class Company {
    private String name;    

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Employee> employees;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The proxy is created for field, it means `employees` will be a proxy over the collection. Now if you try to iterate over the elements of the collection, there are basically two possibilities:

1. If you're not in a transaction, `LazyInitializationException` will be thrown. This is good because you know, that you have to fetch them eagerly is this query.
2. If you're within a transaction, then hibernate will fetch every element that you're iterating over. That's a huge performance overhead, because you need to fire a query to fetch the parent entity and then one query for each child. If there are `N` children, you need to make `N+1` calls to the database, this is also called [N + 1 select problem](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-detect-the-n-plus-one-query-problem-during-testing/).

Comment: thanks for reply. I want to know exact proxy implementation for "employees" collection.

Comment: @RohitJadhav the "exact implementation" is not specified by hibernate. It may change from version to version. It may even change between two runs of the same program. It can be a hard coded implementation, it can be a Proxy, it can even be runtime code generation... and it can even be altered by *your* configuration with listeners. So out of pure curiosity, you have to check hibernate's source codeand your exact SessionFactory config. But for any other purpose, you'd better just limit yourself to the fact that the implementation respects the contract of the collection interface.